# Mutt scripting: interactive dialog macro using `dialog`

Tags: mutt

I would like to do the following:

- Press a macro combination
- Enter a script of my own making (Python) which has user interaction (think: UNIX `dialog` utility for shell scripts)
- Do some processing based on the dialog response
- Run some *other* `mutt` macro based on the dialog response (e.g. if X, do Y; else do Z)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  The macro to run your script should be done like:

```
macro index X "<enter-command>source /path/to/your/command|<enter>"
```

Replacing `index` and `X` with the menu name and key that you want to use.  Note the `|` after the command name.

In order to interact with the terminal, the script will need to reopen `/dev/tty`.  The script can then send back to STDOUT muttrc commands to cause other actions. To run a macro you can send back `push Y` where `Y` is the key to which the macro is bound.